# strings.formatnumber is limiting to 15 characters?

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have a .net visual basic project that uses the function `Strings.formatnumber` this is used because of its flexibility, namely the number of decimal places allowed with a dynamic variable.  However I have come across a nasty bug in that this function seems to round everything to 15 digits

so

```
?  Strings.FormatNumber("123456789012345.66", 2,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.True,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False)
Results 123456789012345.00

?  Strings.FormatNumber("12345678901234.66", 2,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.True,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False)
Results 12345678901234.60

?  Strings.FormatNumber("1234567890123.66", 2,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.True,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False)
Results 1234567890123.66

?  Strings.FormatNumber("1234567890123456666.66", 2,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.True,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False,Microsoft.VisualBasic.TriState.False)
Results 1234567890123460000.00
```

So two questions

- Why does this function do this?
- Is there a .net function that we can use that will turn strings into numbers and return a string and where the number of decimals can be dynamic?

Comment: No need for `Strings.FormatNumber`, `String.Format` covers all these use-cases. I would definitely advise you to use the latter instead of this VB-specific library function. Also, what do you need more than 15 decimal places for? The applications where that’s required are quite limited.

Comment: Let me clarify, I need 15 left of the decimal and only two right.  However, this is part of the generic control so the next person may want 11 left and 4 right.  So how with String.format do I format the string properly to the correct decimal places

Comment: Well as the answers say you cannot do this *regardless* of the formatting function because `double` doesn’t have the necessary precision. However, what do you mean with “15 left” at all? How do you imagine that controlling digits left of the decimal point works? For instance, how would you want to display the number “12345” with two digits in front of the decimal point?

Comment: So we have a maxLength property and a decimal property.  So if you set maxLength to 18 and decimal places 2 then that is interpreted as 15 left of the decimal place, the decimal place, and 2 right of the decimal place.  Now it being a universal control someone might say MaxLength 10 decimals 4 so that would be 5.4.  what I learned is the function above is called to strip out any currency signs, and group separators and to round to the nearest decimal place

Comment: That didn’t really help. Again: could you show me what the display would look like in the specific case I mentioned?

Comment: For instance, how would you want to display the number “12345” with two digits in front of the decimal point? This can be displayed as 12345.00, if decimal place is two, or 12345.0000 if decimal place is 4 or 12,345.00 if group numbers is on.  or (12,345.00) if negative parentheses is on.

Answer (score 2):

[double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx) is defined as having 15-16 digits precision.

You may need to use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead, which offers 28 digits.

Added VB.Net links for [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx) and [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx)

Comment: I don't think I have control over the FormatNumber function.  I pass in a string and get back a properly formatted string.

Comment: @Mike:- Try to use String.Format method

Comment: See part of the discussion above, basically is there a way to format the string to a number of decimal places

Answer (score 2):

Double is defined with 15-16 digit precision.

Try [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead.

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to
>   floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a
>   smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary
>   calculations. The approximate range and precision for the decimal type
>   are shown in the following table.

Comment: @devio One second difference between answers

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a .net function that we can use that will turn strings into numbers and return a string and where the number of decimals can be dynamic?

Here's a simple wrapper for the FormatNumber method that allows you to specify, the maximum length with padding for integral portion, decimal places, thousands separator and negative parentheses:

```
Private Function MyFormatNumber(input As String, MaxLength As Integer, Optional RightDecimal As Integer = 2, Optional Thousands As TriState = TriState.UseDefault, Optional Negative As TriState = TriState.UseDefault) As String
    Dim TempNumber As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(input)
    Dim DecimalIndex As Integer = Decimal.Truncate(Math.Abs(TempNumber)).ToString.Length
    Dim LeftPad As Integer = (MaxLength - RightDecimal) - DecimalIndex
    MyFormatNumber = Strings.FormatNumber(TempNumber, RightDecimal, TriState.True, Negative, Thousands)
    If MyFormatNumber.StartsWith("(") Then
        MyFormatNumber = "(" + MyFormatNumber.Substring(1).PadLeft((MyFormatNumber.Length - 1) + LeftPad, "0"c)
    Else
        MyFormatNumber = MyFormatNumber.PadLeft(MyFormatNumber.Length + LeftPad, "0"c)
    End If
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Dim numberstr As String = ("-12345678901234566.12347", 22, 4, TriState.True, TriState.True)
```

The output is:

```
?numberstr
"(012,345,678,901,234,566.1235)"
```

This assumes that you are validating the strings to be a number type.  If not you can use the TryParse method instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) only has 15–16 *decimal* digits of precision. While there can be more digits, they are mostly garbage. Some languages/environments opt to show you the complete number if you want to, but that's of little use because all those digits aren't meaningful; they're unreliable in calculations, don't really behave like you would expect numbers to do, etc. They are artifacts of conversion of binary to decimal, essentially. .NET therefore rounds to double's decimal precision automatically for display purposes. It doesn't deceive you into thinking that the number is more precise than it actually is.

Mind you, there are instances when you *want* those digits to be displayed (e.g. when demonstrating to someone that there's really 50 digits following), but that's not possible in .NET.